# Face recognition doesn't work on Jetson Nano

Tags: python, nvidia-jetson-nano

I want to minimize my face recognition system from PC to a Jetson Nano board

I use this example code:
https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition/blob/master/examples/facerec_from_webcam_faster.py

The system works well when running on PC, it can recognize known faces. But when I move the code to Jetson Nano, the system can't recognize known faces.
Is there any additional configuration for the ARM processor?

Comment: As it is stated in the README.md of the repo:
`There is current a bug in the CUDA libraries on the Jetson Nano that will cause this library to fail silently if you don't follow the instructions in the article to comment out a line in dlib and recompile it.`
Have you tried that?

Comment: not yet, i want to do that first @jgorostegui

Comment: i just done what you said, but my system still can't recognize known faces @jgorostegui

Answer (score 0):

You have to install all the dependencies first and I am posting the link and commands if you r using TensorFlow. You have to build OpenCV also in Jetson Nano.

https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/frameworks/install-tf-jetson-platform/index.html

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install libhdf5-serial-dev hdf5-tools libhdf5-dev zlib1g-dev zip libjpeg8-dev liblapack-dev libblas-dev gfortran
```

**Install and upgrade pip3.**

```
$ sudo apt-get install python3-pip
$ sudo pip3 install -U pip testresources setuptools
```

**Install the Python package dependencies.**

```
$ sudo pip3 install -U numpy==1.16.1 future==0.17.1 mock==3.0.5 h5py==2.9.0 keras_preprocessing==1.0.5 keras_applications==1.0.8 gast==0.2.2 futur
```